# c++98 in Visual Studio 2019 using Clang as a frontend?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang, c++98

So, I'm using clang as a frontend for Visual Studio 2019 and cmake.
Also I want to build my project throught c++98 standart, I thought that clang may allows this, but it seems like can't or can? Maybe there have some flags or smth?

So, my *CMakeLists.txt:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11 FATAL_ERROR)

project(sink)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Xclang -std=c++98 -Xclang -pedantic")

set(SRC_DIR     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(BUILD_DIR   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${BUILD_DIR}/bin")

file(GLOB SOURCES "${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp" "${SRC_DIR}/*.cc" "${SRC_DIR}/*.c")
file(GLOB HEADERS "${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h" "${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.hpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

And *CMakeSettings.json*:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=\"C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe\" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=\"/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc\" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=\"/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1\"",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```

So here I had a lot of errors like:

```
  In file included from C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vadefs.h:32:
E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\include\vadefs.h(151,27): error : expected parameter declarator
              static_assert(!__vcrt_va_list_is_reference<_Ty>::__the_value,
                            ^
E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\include\vadefs.h(151,27): error : expected ')'
  E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\include\vadefs.h(151,26):  note: to match this '('
              static_assert(!__vcrt_va_list_is_reference<_Ty>::__the_value,
                           ^
E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\include\vadefs.h(151,13): error : C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
              static_assert(!__vcrt_va_list_is_reference<_Ty>::__the_value,
```

But I think this is expected, because in c++98 there wasn't type_traits, etc.
So, there only one way it's replacing the msvc compiler with an older version or can something else be done? And then is there any way to build c++98 on windows but without using MINGW?

Comment: I'm not sure about VS2019, but 2017 only supports C++14 or newer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that 2019 support the same stack of standards as well. Then is there any way to build c++98 on windows but without using MINGW?